# Android Hilt. Is it possible to Inject one ViewModel into another?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I have a `ViewModel` class:

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
open class AppViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
): ViewModel(){

    val isLoading: MutableState<Boolean> = mutableStateOf(false)

    fun setIsLoading(isLoading: Boolean){
        this.isLoading.value = isLoading
    }
}
```

This class should hold the general App state.

Then I have another `ViewModel` class, inside which I want to be able to modify the `AppViewModel` state. E.g. when fetching data I want to set `isLoading` to true and render the progress bar.
The `ChildViewModel` class that should modify `AppViewModel` state:

```kotlin
class ChildViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: Repository,
    private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
): AppViewModel(savedStateHandle){

    ...

    fun onTriggerEvent(event: RestApiEvents) {
        try {
            viewModelScope.launch {
                // this should change the state in AppViewModel
                isLoading.value = true
                when(event) {
                    is SearchEvent -> {
                        search(event.s)
                    }
                    else -> {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Event not found")
                    }
                }
                // this should change the state in AppViewModel
                isLoading.value = false
            }
        }
        catch (e: Exception){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    private suspend fun search(s: String) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So, I'm new to compose and I was trying to make the exact same thing.
The compiler didn't let me inject the AppViewModel as a dependency to the ChildViewModel, so I ended up doing the following:

1. Created a data class (AppStateHolder) to store loading bool value.
2. At AppViewModel I inject AppStateHolder as dependency.
3. Added to appmodule the hilt reference generator with @Singleton and @Provides annotation.
4. I inject at ChildViewModel reference to AppStateHolder.
5. AppStateHolder has a mutable state for the isLoading boolean.
6. At AppViewModel init block I collect the appStateHolder values and update the mutable state accordingly.
7. When necessary at ChildViewModel I update AppStateHolder values.

So you can inject AppStateHolder, update its values, and when you make this, AppViewModel will be notified and updates its own state.
The setback is, if you havea lot of ui state variables at AppViewModel you have to replicate them at AppStateHolder and always observe them at AppViewModel.

I know it's not the best option, but I will be looking for other ways or till someone comes with a better solution.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, I needed session view model, indicating that I needed it injected everywhere, in almost all view models. So, there was eg. `LoginViewModel` created like this:

```
@HiltViewModel
class LoginViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val loginRepository: LoginRepository,
    private val sessionViewModel: SessionViewModel,
) : BaseViewModel<LoginContract.Event, LoginContract.State, LoginContract.Effect>() {
    ...
```

and then I needed a bit of a hack for `SessionViewModel`:

```
/** Note: not @HiltViewModel since it is not possible to inject HiltViewModel into another one.
 * So, this is left to be a viewModel, but it is injected via [AppModule.provideSessionViewModel()]
 */
class SessionViewModel @Inject constructor() :
    BaseViewModel<SessionContract.Event, SessionContract.State, SessionContract.Effect>() {
    ...
```

```
@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideSessionViewModel() : SessionViewModel {
   return SessionViewModel()
}
```

Then, it can be injected on UI if needed there:

```
@Inject
lateinit var sessionViewModel: SessionViewModel
```